# Java EE web-application file creation

Tags: java, web-applications, file-upload, jakarta-ee

I'm developing a web application in java to control my stock and do some other things. I upload files through a JSF component. This files are images. Anyway, my question is, I want these images to be stored in the web application's resource folder. More specifically in a subfolder named "userUploads". I create a File object but how do I a get a String representing that path?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your files to be stored in your "web application's resource folder" I'm guessing you mean a folder called 'resources' inside the 'webroot'. While this is not really the best approach, you can achieve this by using the `ServletContext`:

`ServletContext sc = httpRequest.getSession().getServletContext();`

```
String path = sc.getPath("resources");
```

or

```
File file = new File(sc.getPath("resources"))
```

Personally, I'd recommend creating your 'uploads' folder outside of your web app's directory, so that it is not replaced during deployment etc.

"I create a File object but how do I a get a String representing that path?"

If you have a `File` object, you can call `myFile.getAbsolutePath()` to get a string representation of the path.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your advice I really appreciate it. One more thing then. I want to store them there because it is really convenient for display in later web pages. Is there anyway I can store them in another folder yet at the same time have them available in my resources folder? Something like a mapping may be?

Comment: Or maybe I can store them there and before deployment I move the files? Plus, I don't want to be annoying but Since the webroot doesn't change often, is there anyway I can access this from a configuration file or maybe not programatically but using CDI?

Comment: The reason I ask for CDI is because I'm using stateless Session EJBs and they can't keep state. I could store it in a Singleton bean but creating one just for that doesn't seem like a way to go.

Comment: you can store them anywhere on any file system you have write permissions/access for.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Get the `HttpSession` from the `HttpServletRequest`.
2. Get the `ServletContext` from the `HttpSession`.
3. Get the absolute path to your installation using the `ServletContext.getRealPath()` method.  The parameter to this method is a path that is relative to your context root.

Here is a link: [ServletContext](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)